# Seleccionar elementos de una tabla que esta en formato lista en R

Tags: r, lista, dataset

Tengo una tabla  en Excel que luce de la siguiente forma:

```
|L#2458852|80  |90   |95   |97.5    |100   |102.5   |105   |110   |115   |120   |__TITLE_ROW___|
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|1W       |1   |2    |3    |4       |5     |6       |7     |8     |9     |10    |ABCDE         |
|2W       |2   |4    |6    |8       |3     |1       |5     |8     |4     |16    |ABFRE         |
|3W       |5   |6    |5    |9       |2     |0       |2     |1     |7     |11    |ABYTE         |
|1M       |2   |4    |2    |8       |6     |1       |4     |8     |3     |16    |CDFRE         |
|2M       |2   |3    |6    |2       |3     |0       |5     |1     |4     |13    |AUTFE         |
|3M       |4   |5    |1    |8       |3     |1       |0     |8     |3     |17    |ABFGT         |
|6M       |2   |3    |2    |6       |3     |1       |8     |7     |2     |11    |GTFRE         |
|9M       |2   |3    |6    |8       |4     |1       |5     |3     |4     |11    |ABTRE         |
|1Y       |7   |4    |5    |8       |4     |2       |5     |6     |4     |18    |ABFFG         |
|18M      |2   |5    |6    |8       |5     |1       |3     |2     |4     |12    |ABOPE         |
|2Y       |2   |7    |6    |3       |3     |2       |0     |3     |5     |16    |GTRRE         |
```

Luego de importarla a R, bajo el nombre `df` necesito seleccionar un elemento de dicha tabla dada una coordenada de fila y otra de columna. En primer lugar, al importar la tabla esta queda de tipo lista:

```
> typeof(df)
[1] "list"
```

Intento convertirlo a dataframe:

```
 df1 = as.data.frame(df)
```

Y luego intento extraer, por ejemplo el primer elemento, y obtengo:

```
> df1["1W","80"]
[1] NA
```

Me di cuenta que los nombres de las filas son:

```
> rownames(df1)
 [1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10" "11"
```

Así que los cambié:

```
rownames(df1) = c("1W","2W","3W","1M","2M","3M","6M","9M","1Y","18M","2Y")
> rownames(df1)
 [1] "1W"  "2W"  "3W"  "1M"  "2M"  "3M"  "6M"  "9M"  "1Y"  "18M" "2Y"
```

Y los nombres de las columnas son:

```
> colnames(df1)
 [1] "L#2458852"     "80"            "85"            "90"            "95"           
 [6] "97.5"          "100"           "102.5"         "105"           "110"          
[11] "115"           "120"           "__TITLE_ROW__"
```

Aún así cuando intento extraer, por ejemplo, la entrada en la primera fila y la primera columna, obtengo:

```
> df1["1W","80"]
[1] NA
```

Yo necesito que se cambien los nombres de las filas y además que la tabla quede en formato dataframe o matrix o datatable porque cuando pregunto por su tipo me sale:

```
> typeof(df1)
[1] "list"
```

No sé como podría hacerlo. Pueden ayudarme?

Comment: intenta con df1 = data.frame(df) y para acceder a una coordenada, este se comporta de manera matricial, para acceder a las filas y columnas, una forma es usar : (df1[i,j]) , es decir, si quieres acceder a la primera fila y primera columna debes usar df1[1,1]

Comment: Si `df1["1W","80"]` te retorna `NA`  eso puede implicar dos cosas 1) que tengas un valor `NA` en la celda, cosa que no parece o 2) que no exista la fila con el nombre `1W`,  revisa bien el paso a paso de tu código, no parece que estuvieras haciendo nada mal.

Answer (score 1):

### Funciones `typeof()` y `class()`

`typeof()` retorna la representación interna de los objetos en R:

```
> df = read.csv("../data/subsetdf.csv")

> typeof(df)

[1] "list"
```

En R, un 'dataframe' es una lista en la cual todas las variables tienen la misma longitud. Para verificar si la tabla que está en la sesión es un "dataframe" se puede extraer el atributo `class()` de dicho objeto usando:

```
> class(df)
[1] "data.frame"
```

Todos los atributos pueden ser visualizados también:

```
> attributes(df)
$names
 [1] "L.2458852" "X80"       "X90"       "X95"       "X97.5"     "X100"     
 [7] "X102.5"    "X105"      "X110"      "X115"      "X120"      "TITLE_ROW"

$class
[1] "data.frame"

$row.names
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
```

Por ello no es necesario transformar la tabla en "dataframe", ya que ella es reconocida en R como tal.

### Seleccionar elementos de una tabla en R-base

Para seleccionar elementos de un dataframe puede usarse la lógica
mencionada por @Bastian Andres, usando el nombre de la tabla e incluyendo el valor de la línea separado por una coma del valor de columna:

`df[i, j]`

Para seleccionar la fila "1w" y todas las columnas:

```
> df[df$L.2458852 == "1W", ]
  L.2458852 X80 X90 X95 X97.5 X100 X102.5 X105 X110 X115 X120 TITLE_ROW
1        1W   1   2   3     4    5      6    7    8    9   10     ABCDE
```

Para seleccionar por posición (primera fila, primera columna):

```
> df[1, 1]
[1] "1W"
```

Para seleccionar varias lineas y las columnas usando el nombre de la variable:

```
> df[1:2, "X80" ]
[1] 1 2

> df[1:2, c("X80", "X95")]
  X80 X95
1   1   3
2   2   6
```

El uso del operador ":" permite seleccionar una secuencia de líneas o columnas

```
> df[1:3, 1:4]
  L.2458852 X80 X90 X95
1        1W   1   2   3
2        2W   2   4   6
3        3W   5   6   5
```

Además de la función "Extract" (`[`), también `subset()` puede ser usada para realizar selección de valores en una tabla:

```
> subset(df, L.2458852 == "1W", select = X80:X95)
  X80 X90 X95
1   1   2   3
```

Datos:

```
> dput(df)
 structure(list(L.2458852 = c("1W", "2W", "3W", "1M", "2M", "3M", 
"6M", "9M", "1Y", "18M", "2Y"), X80 = c(1L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 
2L, 2L, 7L, 2L, 2L), X90 = c(2L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 7L), X95 = c(3L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 
6L), X97.5 = c(4L, 8L, 9L, 8L, 2L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 3L), X100 = c(5L, 
3L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 3L), X102.5 = c(6L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), X105 = c(7L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 
0L, 8L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 0L), X110 = c(8L, 8L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 8L, 7L, 
3L, 6L, 2L, 3L), X115 = c(9L, 4L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 5L), X120 = c(10L, 16L, 11L, 16L, 13L, 17L, 11L, 11L, 18L, 
12L, 16L), TITLE_ROW = c("ABCDE", "ABFRE", "ABYTE", "CDFRE", 
"AUTFE", "ABFGT", "GTFRE", "ABTRE", "ABFFG", "ABOPE", "GTRRE"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))
```